# Dynamically checking if class name is a child class of XYZ in php

Tags: php, class

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends C {}

$class="C";
if ($class instanceof A) {  //This is just for demonstration - I know instanceof won't work!!!
   $object=new $class("","",1)
}
```

How can a check the string "C" to check that this classname is a child of A?

I looked into `is_a()` but it doesn't help.

I am specifically asking for "C" as I am getting the class name dynamically and I can't instantiate without knowing what parameters to pass to constructor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's reflection class to look at class inheritance given a string name.  For example, you could easily build an array of all parent classes like this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('whatever');

$parents = array();
$current_class = $class;
while ($current_class = $current_class->getParentClass()) {
    $parents[] = $current_class->getName();
}
var_dump($parents);
```

Of course you may find this more troublesome than you instantiating an object an using `instanceof`.

The `ReflectionClass` also has a lot of other interesting methods that might help you since it seems you are interested in finding out properties of a class just given it's name.

Check the link for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

For example, you could get the information on parameters needed for the current class' constructor like this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('whatever');
$const_params = $class->getConstructor()->getParameters();
var_dump($const_params);
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks interesting. I edited question to explain that I can't instantiate!

Comment: Thanks again! I in fact used your second example of getConstructor()->getParameters() in combination with isOptional(), getDefault() and isArray() to do what I needed. My problem was that I am using a library of classes which inherit from each other and have different amount of params required by constructor with some having default values and my code is dynamically instantiating a class based on meta data.

Comment: @neyl No problem. Glad to have helped. As you can see, PHP offers pretty powerful reflection tools.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`is_a()`](http://php.net/is_a), [`is_subclass_of()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php), or [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php).

**Note:** These functions require an instance of the object in question, not just a string.

Comment: My question was how can I check a string! The docs on get_parent_class seem to imply that it can be used to check Class or Object but is_subclass_of is only for instance but I haven't tested!?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary You actually can do this using PHP's `ReflectionClass`. See my answer here for more info.

Comment: @`These functions require an instance of the object in question, not just a string.`: that answer is kind of old, so maybe it was true at the time.  But it's not so now, they can accept class names rather than just instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need instance of Object to use `instanceof` it should have been : [PHP DOC on instanceOF](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php)

```
$class =  "C";
if (new $class instanceof A) {
    var_dump("Ok");
}
```

Or Simply

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("C");
if ($class->getParentClass()->name == "A") {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: I am specifically asking for "C" as I am getting the class name dynamically and I can't instantiate without knowing what parameters to pass to constructor!